# Redirect Apache virtual host to virtual machine

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization

I have a dedicated server running apache2 and I want to have several virtual machine (for different development environment). I already succeeded creating virtual machines using virtualbox.

My server has a static IP on the web, and I have a domain name.

I would like to make my subdomain via virtual hosts on apache redirecting to a virtual machine.
Is it possible ? How ?

I'm sorry if a question like this already exists, I don't know what keywords to search.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be what you're after? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [setup NAT in virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for the services you want to expose on your guest virtual machines.

Then in your apache configuration add the reverse proxy configuration.

Assuming your host's port `7890` translates to your guest's port `80` (or the relevant port for the service you are exposing) you could do the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/demo/public_html
    ServerName demo.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/demo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/demo.-access.log common

    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:7890
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:7890

</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to enable the `proxy` and `proxy_http` apache modules (`sudo a2enmod http http_proxy` on Ubuntu).